# Regex lookbehind and lookahead doesn't find any match

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of data that I need to parse and output in different format. The data looks something like this:

```
tag="001">utb20181009818<
tag="003">CZ PrNK<
...
```

And now, I want to extract 'utb20181009818' after after 'tag="001">' and before the last '<'

This is my code in python:

```
 regex_pattern = re.compile(r'''(?=(tag="001(.*?)">)).*?(?<=[<])''')
 ID = regex_pattern.match(one_line)
 print(ID)
```

My variable one_line already contains the necessary data and I just need to extract the value, but it doesn't seem to match no matter what I do. I looked at it for hours, but doesn't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can use tag="\d+">(.*?)< and capture group 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regex `tag=\"001\">(.*?)<` and capture the first group `ID.group(1)`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/2I7UCQ/2)

Comment: `\1` is the syntax for a *backreference*, but OP wants to *extract* that group, which is a bit different (at least in Python)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that lookaheads don't move the match position to the right because they don't match anything - they only *look*.

Obviously, utilizing a match group as suggested would be the simplest way to go here, as you wouldn't have to take pains to avoid matching the parts you don't want.

But if your "001" *isn't* variable length, I think what you want is actually a  lookbehind/lookahead (not lookahead/lookbehind):

`(?<=tag="001">).*(?=<)`

https://regex101.com/r/rMQnna/3/